# Running kNN function in R

Tags: r, knn

I have the following data

```
structure(list(Color = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Size = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), Act = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Age = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1,0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Inflated = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F","F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T")), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have used this code to try to run a knn test on the data set. It has worked on a data set I used before and I have adapted it to fit this one.

```
Inf_True <- originaldata%>%
  filter(Inflated == "T")

Inf_False <- originaldata%>%
  filter(Inflated == "F")

set.seed(4567)
# samples
ran_true <- sample(1:nrow(Inf_True), 0.8*nrow(Inf_True))
ran_false <- sample(1:nrow(Inf_False), 0.8*nrow(Inf_False))
ran <- sample(1:nrow(originaldata), 0.8*nrow(originaldata))

# Create training set 
Training_set <- rbind(Inf_True[ran_true,], Inf_False[ran_false,])

# Create testing set
Test_set <- rbind(Inf_True[-ran_true,], Inf_False[-ran_false,])

# extract 5th column of train dataset because it will be used as 'cl' argument in knn function
target_category <- originaldata[ran,5]
a<-target_category$Inflated
aa<-factor(a)

# extract 5th column of test dataset to measure the accuracy
test_category <- originaldata[-ran,5]

library(class)
## Knn = 1
#run knn function
print("Knn = 1")
knn_one <- knn(Training_set, Test_set, cl=aa, k=1)
```

I Get this error:

Warning: NAs introduced by coercionWarning: NAs introduced by coercionError in knn(Training_set, Test_set, cl = aa, k = 1) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)

I think its to do with "a" but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your character columns into numbers:

```
Training_set$Inflated <- as.numeric(as.factor(Training_set$Inflated))
Test_set$Inflated <- as.numeric(as.factor(Test_set$Inflated))
knn_one <- knn(Training_set, Test_set, cl=aa, k=3)
```

They can't be text (character).

Comment: You are right. But the documentation for `train` and `test` says: matrix or data frame, although `as.matrix` is used in the knn function.

Comment: well, the documentation is not technically wrong, it still accepts (and works with) data.farmes, its just lacking. It should have also stated that all inputs must be numeric.